# HTML Button closing Bootstrap Modal

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, twitter-bootstrap

I have a simple form inside a Bootstrap modal popup. The form was working fine until I needed to add a button to perform a simple calculation based on some values entered into the form.

The button just has a jQuery click event which grabs the values from the form elements, does the calculation the writes that value into a text box. When the form is not in the modal, it works just fine. Zero errors. When the form is in the modal clicking the button closes the modal and I cannot see why.

I have stripped back the button to bare bones and even removed the jquery code in the click event handler.. it still closes the modal. I have removed the form action event (points to a .php script), but the modal still closes.

When it closes I see that the browser address bar is filled with the URL for the page with all the form values as params as the field were populated when I clicked the button.

Can anyone tell me how I can get this button to just be a trivial button I can use for this purpose and NOT close the modal?

Answer (score 1):

> I have removed the form action event (points to a .php script), but the modal still closes.

Removing the `action` attribute just sets the action to the URL of the current page. It doesn't prevent the form from being submitted.

> Can anyone tell me how I can get this button to just be a trivial button I can use for this purpose and NOT close the modal?

## The crappy quick way

`<button type="button">` will make the button a JavaScript only button and not a submit button

## The proper way

In your event handler function, capture the event object and call its `preventDefault()` method.

Make sure that on those occasions [when the JS fails](http://kryogenix.org/code/browser/everyonehasjs.html), the server *does the right thing* and provides a sensible response for the form submission.

Comment: Thank you thank you thank you... setting button to type="button" did it!

Answer (score 1):

The probelm is very likely that the button submits the form. Try specifying `<button type="button">` or add a `evt.preventDefault()` in the click handler.

Comment: Thank you so much! Setting the button to type="button" fixed it for me.